# AWS 2023 AMI Linux installation of epel-release-latest-8

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install the following on an EC2 instance and receiving the following error message:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-0-7 ~]$ sudo dnf install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:30:04 ago on Sat Jun 24 07:59:46 2023.
epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm                                                                    581 kB/s |  25 kB     00:00    
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides redhat-release >= 8 needed by epel-release-8-19.el8.noarch
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EPEL repo is not supported on Amazon Linux 2023.

From the docs

*Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) is a project in the Fedora community with the objective of creating a large array of packages for enterprise-level Linux operating systems. The project has primarily produced RHEL and CentOS packages. Amazon Linux 2 features a high level of compatibility with CentOS 7. As a result, many EPEL7 packages work on Amazon Linux 2. However, AL2023 doesn't support EPEL or EPEL-like repositories.*

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#epel

It's easy enough to spin up another instance so I'm just going to spin up an Amazon Linux 2 AMI and do the work on there instead.